# Update Record Server Behavior blows error ( part of CS5.5 standard installation) Anybody know a fix?

Tags: dreamweaver, sql-update

The UpdateRecord.js, to be found on Windows 7 at ..ProgramFiles(x86(/Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5/configuration/ServerBehaviors/Php_MySQL/UpdateRecord.js  causes an error when it is selected from the SERVER BEHAVIORS menu.  This happens BEFORE you I enter anything into the fields.

The error states:  "While executing onLoad in  UpdateRecord.htm, the following JavaScript error(s) occured: At line 687 of file "........UpdateRecord.js":  name has no properties.  I've looked at the code and it is beyond my comprehension.  Something about the NAME of a value in the node list.... I just don't have the chops to go rewriting Adobe's code. Does anybody know what to do about this?

About my system:  Windows 7, 64bit,   CS5.5 (on a lease so it is up to date) using PHP and MySQL, on a remote dedicated server running Apache on Linux.   :<)McFrisco

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, maybe there's input has blank name or without name.

Answer (score 0):

a quick temporary solution is close or change the Server Behavior tab in the DreamWeaver.
you will not see that message until you reopen or reuse the Server Behavior tab group.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the type.

Error will occurs ---> input name="privilages" id="privilages" value=""

Change to ---> input **type="text"** name="privilages" id="privilages" value=""

Please check the type of all Text boxs, Radio Buttons, Select Boxs, ect... in your form.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this quickly when I realised that one of the fields in the form had the name missing! Added a name and the Update Record behaviour worked normally.